# remove some signs from a txt file

Tags: objective-c

i am saving a `NSMutuablearray` to a text file, he has `NSNmbers` in it .

when i open it (it sent to my emal) i see :

```
<integer>-13</integer>
<integer>-80</integer>
<integer>-15</integer>
```

i want ONLY the numbers without this `<integer>` sign.
there is a way of removing that? or put that numbers not in nsmutuable ?

code :

```
//add numbers
     for(int i=0;i<417;i++)
     {
         int x= [globals sharedGlobals].bufBuf[i];
         NSNumber* myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: x];
         [samples addObject:myNumber];
     }

//create file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/samplesTest.txt", documentsDirectory];
    [samples writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO];
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove them using objective-c? Or you can use any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare a string with your numbers, and save it to the file:

```
NSArray *numbers =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
            nil
        ];
NSString *res = [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSError *error;
[res writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                      error:&error];
```

Comment: thanks i did that he says: writeToFile is deprecated. whats wrong here ?

Comment: @user1280535 Oops, I used a deprecated overload. See the edit - it should fix the deprecation warning.